# How to access DataItem value of repeater in repeater1_ItemDataBound

Tags: asp.net, repeater

How can i access `File_Name1`s value in `repeater1_ItemDataBound`.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repeater1" runat="server">

   <input type="hidden" id="filenameid" 
               value="<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container,"DataItem.File_Name1") %>" />

</asp:Repeater>
```

I tried a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure that your input is a server control `<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="filenameid"/>` and then in your `repeater1_ItemDataBound` event use:

```
HiddenField filenameid = e.DataItem.FindControl("filenameid") as HiddenField;
```

You will have access to its Value.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

what I can see you have forgotten the [ItemTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemtemplate.aspx)

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repeater1" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
        <input type="hidden" id="filenameid" 
                                   value="<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container,"DataItem.File_Name1") %>" />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
     {
          //((YourClass)e.Item.DataItem).PropertyName
     }
}
```